# Multiple subdomain redirect in server block with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect multiple subdomains on my server to another with Nginx. Here is what I am doing so far:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name firstsub.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://firstsub.anothersite.co$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name secondsub.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://secondsub.anothersite.co$request_uri;
}
```

because I have about 10 subdomains, adding it like that would be really ugly. Is there a way to write several domain redirects in one server block? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the domains have a consistent pattern, you can use a *regular expression* with the `server_name` directive.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)\.example\.com$;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain.anothersite.co$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.